# How to disable UI Tool

Tags: iphone

if in my view there are buttons and UITextfields 
and i want to create a condition that whenever ,i click on any button at that time  other UIButton and UITextfield will be disable.

How Can i do that???????

Comment: To accept previous answers, click the green checkmark next to the response that best answered the question.

Answer (score 3):

Start by reading the documentation. The mentioned functionality is very clearly defined for UIButton, UITextField and their super classes.

The property you are looking for is called *enabled*